# How to send an file with $http.post in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2

How can I send a file with vue.js?

The following code is not working for me:

```
<span title="Upload" class="badge badge-info">
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" @change="uploadData" class="archive" > <i id="iarchive" class="fa fa-upload"></i> 
</span>
```

When I make `console.log(this.request.file)` I get `FILE [object File]`.

Here is the .js:

```
  uploadData: function(e) {
                var files = e.target.files[0];


                this.request.action = 'upload';
                this.request.file = files;
                console.log("FILE "+this.request.file);

                this.$http.post('data/getData.php', {
                data: this.request,    
                headers: {
                           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'                   
                }
              }
               ).then(function(response) {

                    console.log("RESPONSE: "+response.body);

            }, function(response) {

                alert("error");
            });
            return false;
        }
```

But in PHP, I can't get the file, the response is :`{} No properties`.

PHP code:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 
$req = $request->data;
echo json_encode($req->file)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add ref attribute to input:

```
<input ref="file-input" .../>
```

In controller you should write action:

```
uploadFile: function () {
  // try to log $refs object for deep understanding
  let fileToUpload = this.$refs.fileInput.files[0];
  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('fileToUpload', fileToUpload);
  this.$http.post ( 'data/getData.php', formData ).then(function () {
    // success actions
  });
}
```

In php endpoint your uploaded files will be in form request object.

Comment: thank for you response, but, now i get :null from php in $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));   
 var_dump($request);  |  https://imgur.com/Dw0XwpU, how recive this file in php?

Comment: Try to dump $_FILES, [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use FormData `append()` function:

```
var files = e.target.files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', files);

this.$http.post('/data/getData.php', formData, {
   headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
})
```

Comment: thank for you response, but, now i get :null from php in $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));   
 var_dump($request);  |  https://imgur.com/Dw0XwpU

Comment: use [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). I see you solved the problem, good luck.