# IFormFile Refuses to upload from vue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, vuetify.js, vue-resource

I'm using vuetify's `v-file-input` component

```
<v-row>
    <v-file-input label="File input"
                    v-model="file" />
    <v-btn depressed
            color="primary"
            @click="uploadClicked">
        Upload
    </v-btn>
</v-row>
```

Trying to post the file with `vue-resource`

```
this.$http.post(`${this.api}FileManager/Folder/${folderId}/File`, this.file);
```

I can see that `this.file` is populated with the selected file, but for some reason I can't get the file to appear in my endpoint in `FileManagerController`:

```
[HttpPost("Folder/{folderId}/File")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(Guid folderId, [FromBody]IFormFile file)
{
    // process the file
}
```

I get this error:

> {"errors":{"":["Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '', line 1, position 2."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|6d17d263-464344720128162b."}

What I tried:

1. Replacing `[FromBody]` with `[FromForm]` : Endpoint is hit but `file` is empty and so is `Request.Form.Files`
2. Removing `[FromBody]` results in HTTP error 'method not allowed'

What is going on here?

Comment: You're sending JSON to an endpoint that accepts a form.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks, how can you tell? and how do I tell it to not do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802040/file-upload-with-asp-net-core-vuejs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502176/how-to-send-an-file-with-http-post-in-vue-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to CodeCaster I found that this is the correct configuration

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.file);
this.$http.post(`${this.api}FileManager/Folder/${folderId}/File`, formData);
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost("Folder/{folderId}/File")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(Guid folderId, IFormFile file)
{
    // process the file
}
```

Note that `[FromBody]` is not required and in fact causes a 415 if not removed